# How can I tell a given package belongs to which jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, packaging

If I'm referencing an external library from an project in Eclipse for instance 'org.eclipse.swt.*', how can I tell what jar-file I need to reference ?

#### EDIT:

I know I can look at the contents of a jar file but that's not very convenient to do. Isn't there any documentation for org.eclipse.swt what jar file a given package is in ?

Comment: You can simply *open* the jar in any tool capable of doing so (jars *are* essentially zip files), e.g. 7zip and looking whats in there.

Comment: @Guy eclipse, check tags.

Comment: You can use the online tool http://www.findjar.com

Answer (score 0):

A jar is a special kind of **zip file** so you could just unpack it and look at it's content. However with packages being a directory structure this isn't very comfortable. What IDE are you using? **Eclipse** for example allows you to open the contents from a jar in the **project explorer view** on the right.

[image: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.2-200606291905/new_noteworthy/images/project_explorer_view.png]

Image from eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

the usual workflow is `ctrl + mouse click` on the class name (or method name) and go to that file, then use `Project Explorer` ->  `Link with Editor` button

[image]

to go see the file location in the project tree

btw, instead of importing like `'org.eclipse.swt.*'` you can also use Eclipse to arrange imports for you by using `ctrl + shift + o`

and btw2, you should just use a tool like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) and forget all about manual referencing of jars :)